# Can I access a database during middleware in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-middleware

I want to create Visitor page

```
private readonly DBDatacontext _db;
private RequestDelegate _requestDelegate;

public VisitorMiddleWare(RequestDelegate requestDelegate, DBDatacontext db)
{
    _requestDelegate = requestDelegate;
    _db = db;
}

public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    string visitorId = context.Request.Cookies["VisitorId"];
    string remoteIpAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

    if (visitorId == null)
    {
        context.Response.Cookies.Append("VisitorId", Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), new 
                  CookieOptions()
            {
                Path = "/",
                HttpOnly = true,
                Secure = false,
            });

        visitorId = context.Request.Cookies["VisitorId"];

        var model = new Visitor()
            {
                Ip = remoteIpAddress
            };

        _db.AddAsync(model);
        _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    await _requestDelegate(context);
}
```

and in the startup

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(VisitorMidlleWare));
```

but I get this error:

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'DBDatacontext' from root provider.

Comment: Have you tried to register the `DbContext` as a service, with `services.AddDbContext<DBDatacontext>(...)`?

Comment: services.AddDbContext<DBDatacontext>(options =>
                     options.UseSqlServer(
                         Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))).AddTransient<IVisitorRepository, VisitorRepository>();

Comment: it was default connection when i use Identity.

Answer (score 3):

Your DB context is not a singleton so you should not resolve it in the constructor.
You can add it instead as a parameter for InvokeAsync:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, DBDatacontext db)
{
}
```

By default an EF DB context is registered as Scoped, which by default means one is created per request.
And you cannot make it a singleton because it is not thread-safe.

InvokeAsync can specify other parameters to get scoped and transient dependencies from the service collection.
You can alternatively access the RequestServices property on the HttpContext to get services dynamically.

More on this and more on my blog ;) https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-di-deep-dive

> Use cases for each approach:
>
> Constructor: Singleton components that are needed for all requests
>
> Invoke parameter: Scoped and transient components that are always necessary on requests
>
> RequestServices: Components that may or may not be needed based on runtime information

Comment: thanks a lot.
i changed my class and it worked fine.

Comment: Awesome :) Probably should've mentioned more about the reason: middleware are only created once, the constructor only runs once. So any per request services cannot be acquired there.

Comment: i think i don't know enough information about singlton,scop and Transient.
i studied this article  and i think better way is when i use Transient.
but at the first i must change all my project.
now i search for write best way for visitor page.
thanks about article.